# Can makefile.am set LDADD for a set of target?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, automake, googletest

I placed unit tests within the same directory of source code. But how could I set the LDADD in Makefile.am for all these unit tests to use specific libraries (e.g google test)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of `LDADD` are used for all target unless this variable is overridden with `target_LDADD`.  So if you have many unit tests, and only a few actual programs, you may use `LDADD` for the unit tests and override it for each program with different linking requirements.

```
LDADD = libtest.a   # Used by default for all targets

# Unit tests, using above LDADD
check_PROGRAMS = one two three
one_SOURCES = one.c
two_SOURCES = two.c
three_SOURCES = three.c

# Main program
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.c
main_LDADD =        # Override the LDADD setting.
```

A similar example can be found in [the documentation of `LDADD`](http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html#Linking).